# Why is the Twitch API giving me an undocumented HTTP 404 error on Check User Subscription By Channel?

Tags: c#, http, twitch

When trying to check whether a user is subscribed to a particular channel using the Twitch API v5, I'm getting an HTTP 404 response from the twitch server. According to the [documentation](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/reference/users#check-user-subscription-by-channel)  that should not happen in v5. v3 used to respond with an http 404 if the user wasn't subscribed but v5 should always respond with a json payload. If the user is not subscribed said payload would have a "status" field with value 404.

I am using the URL provided by twitch's documentation: https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/012345678/subscriptions/876543210

I am correctly connectiong to twitch since the API requests performed immediately before this one to get authorization from the user and their userid all work.

I have tested this both with users that are and users that aren't subscribed to the channel in question; both cause the same reaction.

The access token used to authorize the operation has scopes **user_subscription** and **user_read**.

In which situations does the twitch API respond like this?

Below is the code that is producing this problem:

```
twitchRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/" + userId + "/subscriptions/" + DB.GetCode("TwitchChannelId"));
twitchRequest.Method = "GET";
twitchRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization: OAuth " + accessToken);
twitchRequest.Headers.Add("Client-ID: " + DB.GetCode("TwitchClientId"))
//this throws a System.Net.WebException
//The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
twitchResponse = twitchRequest.GetResponse();
```

Comment: [here](https://hastebin.com/jopepiqola.cs) is version of the code that includes the other requests (successfully) made to twitch as well. I thought it inappropriate to clutter the question with what seemed like useless code. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You're requesting the default v3 of the API, which uses usernames instead of IDs. To use v5, add

```
twitchRequest.Headers.Add("Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json");
```